# working with threads in winforms

Tags: wpf, multithreading, winforms

How to make the same thing on WinForms, that I have in WPF application (Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate):

```
public class Fullscreen
    {
public Fullscreen(Action goFullScreen)
        {
            goFullScreenMode = goFullScreen;
        }
public void Make()
        {
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
                {
                    goFullScreenMode();
                });
}
}
```

I need to access to MainWindow.cs in WinForms that сontains:

```
public void GoFullScreen()
        {
            TopMost = true;
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
```

That I register like this in MainWindow_Load

```
_fullscreen = new Fullscreen(GoFullScreen);
RegisterJavaScriptObject("__fullscreen", _fullscreen);
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?please be more specific

Comment: You don't need the Dispatcher or Invoke in WPF either. In both stacks, use `async/await` and `IProgress< T>`

Comment: Why are you calling `RegisterJavaScriptObject` in a *Winforms* application?

Comment: I calling it in Chromium brouser.

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos could you give a code example for my case with WinForms. I don't work with IProgress< T> yet.